# how to display year and month as 1Y2M in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, date, intervals, date-formatting

I have a query to retrieve the number of months between two dates -

```
select Trunc(Months_between(Trunc(SYSDATE), CUR_EFF_DATE ) / 12, 1) 
from xyz
```

Now this query returns data like - 0.1, 1.5 etc. I want the query to give results such as 1yr 2 months, 1 month etc. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: What is the desired result if the two dates you are comparing are, for example, `22 JAN 2020` and `17 APR 2020`? You seem to want integer number of years, integer number of months. So, how will you handle examples like the one I gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go [by the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-9B4F00D0-821A-4342-95AA-30CA43DBA124):

> Interval data types do not have format models. Therefore, to adjust their presentation, you must combine character functions such as `EXTRACT` and concatenate the components.

An example follows, which looks a lot like your use case, and can be adapted as follows:

```
select 
    extract(year from (sysdate - cur_eff_date) year to month)
    || ' year(s) '
    || extract(month from (sysdate - cur_eff_date) year to month)
    || ' month(s)' 
    as date_diff
from xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try computing the years and months using division along with modulus, then display the output the way you want.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), CUR_EFF_DATE) / 12, 1) AS num_months
    FROM xyz
)

SELECT
    TO_CHAR(FLOOR(num_months / 12)) || 'Y' ||
        TO_CHAR(MOD(num_months, 12)) || 'M' AS output
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRUNC` and `MOD` functions as following:

```
SELECT TRUNC(MONS/12) || 'Y' || MOD(MONS,12) || 'M' 
FROM
(SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), CUR_EFF_DATE) MONS
FROM XYZ)
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

The character conversion will happen by default and you should not divide by 12 in the num_months calculation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE+365,SYSDATE),0) AS num_months
    FROM dual
)

SELECT
    FLOOR(num_months/12) || 'Y' || MOD(num_months, 12) || 'M' AS output
FROM cte;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you need to apply `FLOOR` to `MOD(num_months, 12)`? That is already an integer since `num_months` is an integer.

Comment: `TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE+365,SYSDATE),0)` would be an integer...In the query `TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE+365,SYSDATE),1)` was being used, which would give a decimal of scale 1...That being said, I can simply use trunc(date,0)...I will edit my answer

Comment: Oh, OK... I didn't notice that you (like the OP) were rounding to one decimal place. Makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` data type, which you could use:

```
select (sysdate - cur_eff_date) year to month as diff from xyz
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=af73605e5856d096b52cffa04dfeea08)</sup>**